# Insert into database MAX(field)+1

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to insert some values into a database, one of the values that I need to insert is;- `MAX(FixedFareID)+1`

As follows:

```
public function fixed($fieldDay) {

    $pdo = new SQL();
    $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

    $this->sql = "INSERT INTO tblfixedfare VALUES (NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '1', '$fieldDay')";
```

Obviously, as it is this will not work, but I am unsure how I could insert the MAX(FixedFareID)+1 value into the database.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you not create an identity column? What version of SQL are you using? MySql? If so: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: I am using MySQL, the ID column is auto-increment, FixedFareID is not unique so I can't use this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tblfixedfare 
select NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '1', '$fieldDay' from tblfixedfare
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it is using a `auto_increment` column (syntax will depend on you SQL engine) or using a sequence.

Comment: I would use this, but I am already using this for the ID column, FixedFareID is not unique, it is always 1 or 2

Comment: Then your query is going to insert 3 into the database is it not? Thus violating that rule... MAX would give you '2', add 1 to that and it's '3'

Comment: Sorry, I typed that wrong, I will be doing two inserts, for these two inserts the fixedfareid is going to be the same

Comment: @nsilva: what DB are you using? a sequence will definitely solve this issue. If you're using Oracle, PostgreSQL, Firebird, you have sequences you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub query:

```
$this->sql = 
  "INSERT INTO tblfixedfare 
  VALUES (NULL, (SELECT MAX(FixedFareID)+1 FROM tblfixedfare), '1', '$fieldDay'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You need a sub-select for your `MAX()`:

```
(SELECT MAX(FixedFareID)+1 FROM tblfixedfare)
```

or, which may be a better and faster, switch your `FixedFareID` to use `auto increment` feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an auto increment field then you can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblfixedfare 
SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '1', '$fieldDay'
FROM tblfixedfare
```

So your code would be:

```
public function fixed($fieldDay) {

    $pdo = new SQL();
    $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

    $this->sql = "INSERT INTO tblfixedfare SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '1', '$fieldDay' FROM tblfixedfare";
```